# beginner webrtc/nodejs issue connecting remote clients

Tags: node.js, laravel, express, webrtc

I'm trying to develop a web application in nodejs. I'm using an npm package called "simple-peer" but i don't think this issue is related to that. I was able to use this package and get it working when integrating it with a laravel application using an apache server as the back end. I could access the host machine through it's IP:PORT on the network and connect a separate client to the host successfully with a peer-to-peer connection. However, I'm now trying to develop this specifically in node without an apache back end. I have my express server up and running on port 3000, I can access the index page from a remote client on the same network through IP:3000. But when I try to connect through webrtc, I get a "Connection failed" error. If I connect two different browser instances on the same localhost device, the connection succeeds.

For reference: i'm just using the copy/pasted code from [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-peer) usage demo. I have the "simplepeer.min.js" included and referenced in the correct directory.

So my main questions are: is there a setting or some webRTC protocol that could be blocking the remote clients from connecting? What would I need to change to meet this requirement? Why would it work in a laravel/webpack app with apache and not with express?

Answer (score 1):

If your remote clients can not get icecandidates, you need TURN server.

When WebRTC Peer behind NAT, firewall or using Cellular Network(like smartphone), P2P Connection will fail.

At that time, for fallback, TURN server will work as a relay server.

I recommend [coTURN](https://github.com/coturn/coturn).

Comment: For fix it, I need logs about SDP negotitation, icecandidates.
You can sure websocket works well?

Comment: i'm not using websockets yet. in the demo i referenced in my link, you just manually input the offer/answer to each peer. It works on two browser tabs on the same device, but not on a client device on the same network.

Comment: Is there a line in each of that offer / answer that starts with a = candidate? Also, does the line include "typ host"?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an simple implementation of simple-peer with nodejs backend for multi-user video/audio chat. You can find the client code in `/public/js/main.js`.  [Github Project](https://github.com/Dirvann/webrtc-video-conference-simple-peer)   and the [Demo](https://dirvann-webrtc-video.herokuapp.com/).

And just like @JinhoJang said. You do need a turn server to pass the information. [Here is a list of public stun/turn servers.](https://gist.github.com/sagivo/3a4b2f2c7ac6e1b5267c2f1f59ac6c6b)